# AJAX issue returning the value

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using a javascript function that calls another javascript function (zConvertEmplidtoRowid) that uses an ajax call that runs a query to return data in a variable (rowid).  My problem is I don't know how to return the data to the original function.

Here is a snippet of the original function calling the ajax function (zConvertEmplidtoRowid)

```
var rowid = zConvertEmplidtoRowid(emplid);
//the alert should show what the query via ajax returned
alert(rowid);
zEmployeePortrait(emplid, ajaxlink);
}
```

And here is the ajax function...I imagine somewhere in here I need to place the return, but I've never used ajax before, so I'm not sure.

```
function zConvertEmplidtoRowid(emplid, ajaxlink, callback) {

  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest == 'undefined') {
            XMLHttpRequest = function() {
                try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0"); } catch(e) {}
                try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); } catch(e) {}
                try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }     catch(e) {}
                try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }  catch(e) {}

            throw new Error('This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest or XMLHTTP.');
            };
        }
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
      var rowid = request.responseText;
      callback(rowid);
    }    
  }

  var ajax_link = ajax_link + "?emplid=" + emplid;
  request.open('GET', ajax_link);
  request.send();
}
```

Comment: Asynchronous calls do not return....

Comment: A couple things. 1) The "A" in AJAX stands for "asynchronous" which means you wont be able to use the normal functional programming that you are used to. 2) You should be using a JavaScript library to handle the low-level mechanics of the AJAX call.

Comment: Can you use php to process your ajax call? I just got downvoted for suggesting use of php

Comment: I'll politely ask again...can you use php?

Answer (score 2):

As @epascarello pointed out, the ajax call is asynchronous and the code you have written is expecting the call to return in a synchronous way.

You have two options:

1) Make the ajax call synchronous (I highly recommend not to take this route).

2) Pass a callback function as a parameter to the function making the ajax call and then invoke the callback function once the call returns.

e.g:

```
function zConvertEmplidtoRowid(emplid, ajaxlink, callback) { //Added a callback function parameter

  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest == 'undefined') {
            XMLHttpRequest = function() {
                try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0"); } catch(e) {}
                try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); } catch(e) {}
                try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }     catch(e) {}
                try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }  catch(e) {}

            throw new Error('This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest or XMLHTTP.');
            };
        }
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
      var rowid = request.responseText;
            //now you invoke the callback passing the rowid as argument
            callback(rowid);
    }    
  }

  var ajax_link = ajax_link + "?emplid=" + emplid;
  request.open('GET', ajax_link);
  request.send();
}

zConvertEmplidtoRowid(emplid, ajaxlink, function(rowId) {
    alert(rowId);
    zEmployeePortrait(emplid, ajaxlink);
});
```

Comment: what does that callback function do?  Is that a built in function or something?

Comment: its the success handler for zConvertEmplidtoRowid function

Comment: @user3586248 Try the updated answer. I named the argument as `rowId` and was using `rowid` in the alert. Fixed the typo now.

Comment: @user3586248 What do you mean by "that still is not working"? What is the error/message you are getting?

Comment: the alert still says undefined

Comment: How are you calling the `zConvertEmplidtoRowid` function? Are you using the sample I have provided or still using the old code?

Comment: I am not..I am using the old code...should we move this to chat and I can show you how it's called if it'd be easier?

Comment: var rowid = zConvertEmplidtoRowid(emplid);
alert(rowid);
zEmployeePortrait(emplid, ajaxlink);

}

Comment: I get the same error message ... anyways .. you cannot mix the sample I provided with the old version of calling the `zConvertEmplidtoRowid` method.

Comment: @user3586248  did you checked the ajax call returns a value?

Comment: Ok I added the other part of your code and the alert doesn't show.  when I checked it in Firebug it says 'callback is not a function'

Comment: it's because you passed the callback function as second parameter to
zConvertEmplidtoRowid  method and second parameter is ajaxlink

Answer (score 0):

As epascarello has implied in his comment, you need to make the javascript call synchronously in order to get a return value...

I tend to use jquery to assist with the call, but a quick google suggests you can do it your way by changing:

request.open('GET', ajax_link);

to:

request.open('GET', ajax_link, false);

and the response is then accessible through:

request.responseText

taken from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests